# Kafka: Topic not present in metadata Exception

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I use the Spring KafkaTemplate abilities to send message in Kafak-topic.

Configuration is:

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin createKafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:2181");
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:2181");
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

 @Bean
 public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

Then I try to send message:

```
@Autowire
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future =
                kafkaTemplate.send("waiting_for_ack",key, value);
```

But I receive the following exception:

```
TimeoutException: Topic waiting_for_ack not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Target topic exist, in which was able to make sure, by:

```
 ./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list _consumer_offsets
  
   waiting_for_ack
```

What am I do wrong, I what way to determine the cause of this exception?

Comment: Use port 9092 in your code... I think part of the confusion is that you should be using `kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server` since Zookeeper flag is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the broker urls instead of the zookeeper url in the  BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG property. You can try checking for it in the

> server.properties

available in `/config` folder under the kafka installation.Usually it would be

> bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092